# How to add custom field in salesforce leads through rest api?

Tags: api, salesforce

Hi
I am currently working on an application which is implementing salesforce.com REST api. I have done all the authentication part and received all the info needed. Now I want my application to push the leads into the customer's account. But the lead fields can be customized and different customer use their different custom fields, so any1 can suggest me how to add that custom field in my form which will be pushed to the customer's salesforce account.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the describe resource in the REST API to obtain the metadata about the Load object, including all the fields.

```
https://{someinstance}.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/lead/describe
```

You can use the list of fields to drive your form, and to control what you subsequently POST to `/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/lead` to create the new lead.

Here's the [link to the REST API pilot docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf) incase you haven't seen them

Comment: Thanx a lot for the info, i tried this /services/data/v20.0/sobjects/lead but I am getting this error response : Array ( [0] => Array ( [message] => The REST API is currently in pilot, and is not enabled for your organization. [errorCode] => API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG ) )  After getting this I tried enabling my api but its still not enabled, do u have any idea how to enable the rest api for our organization ?

Answer (score 0):

No idea if the REST API supports `describe()` calls, they're a way of querying for all metadata about table (columns, their types etc). In normal webservice API this info can be found at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm#topic-title

Answer (score 0):

the Metadata REST API was put on hold by Salesforce, so there is no REST API for Metadata (there is some limited support in the Tooling REST API, but not enough to create an object).

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20763/creating-a-custom-object-using-rest-api